# How to delete extra window in google chrome

Tags: google-chrome, html

I've had some sort of hack into my Google Chrome source code. All my chrome tabs include this annoying window in the lower left. This is my first post to this community so I can't share an image, but I will post when I can.

Can anyone tell me how to remove the code creating this window?

- I know the code was added through a malicious software that I've already uninstalled.
- The window changes font colors based on the source tab's content (CSS?).
- If I right-click on the window, I can go into "inspect element" and delete the code block to remove the window. This codeblock is originating from something in Chrome (not a local machine) so I'm asking how to prevent this codeblock from building this window each time a tab opens.

Comment: Have you checked if you have any odd extensions within Chrome still? Often these can be responsible

Comment: Almost certain an extension, disable the weird sounding ones one by one and restart Chrome each time, you'll find the box will disappear at some point. Post a picture of your extensions or write them in a list and I will tell you what to disable to speed up the process.

Comment: Please share a link to a screenshot of that window. Upload it anywhere like tinypic.com etc.

Comment: Upload your image to [Imgur](http://www.imgur.com) and you will get a link you can share. [Edit] your question to include this link and someone with sufficient reputation will inline the image for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you are compiling your own Chromium browser, it's quite unlikely that someone has busted the source code for your browser.

Common causes for this sort of behaviour include Viruses/spyware etc, dodgy Add-Ons, cached javascript files, a third party executable running and hooking into your chrome process.

**Start in Safe Mode**  Most web browsers have a safe mode which starts your browser with addons disabled.  This will allow you to see if your issue is being caused by an addon and will allow you to disable them all.  You can then start enabling your addons one at a time until you see the issue and can pinpoint the offender

**Is all your software up to date?**  Ensure that Windows, your AntiVitus, AntiSpyware, browser and addons are all the latest version.  A lot of exploits target out of date software and exploit bugs which are fixed in newer versions of applications.

**Reset your Browser**.  Most modern browsers including Chrome have the functionality to reset the browser and your profile within it... this will kill off any addons that could be responsible for the issues you are seeing

**Reinstall your Browser**  This is just one step further along the same route - a reinstall will hopefully mop up any infected DLLs etc that could be forming your problem

**Full Scans**  Install a good AV, update it to the latest definitions and scan your machine fully.  It may also be worth sourcing a few free AVs, installing - updating - scanning - uninstalling as no single AV can catch everything (and haivng multiple installed can cause real headaches).  This also goes for anti-malware and anti spyware solutions.

if none of the above fixes it - try windows in safe mode to rule out another exe running on your PC and injecting the code.. then you can use MSCONFIG to start disabling processes and services that could be responsible.  CCleaner is also useful for this.

Hopefully some of this advice will help you figure it out - but I very much doubt chrome itself has been hacked.

Comment: Nice comprehensive list for resolving a host of browser issues. In Chrome "Reset Settings" (at very bottom of advanced settings) seems to have worked.

Comment: But still you should definitely perform a full system antivirus scan, and a second opinion anti malware scanner as Malwarebytes.